# Why does df -h show so much wasted space on /dev/shm, /sys/fs/cgroup and /run/shm?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I recently setup a Ubuntu 20.04 server virtual machine and when running df -h, I see the following:

```
    Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                               2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                              595M  1.2M  594M   1% /run
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   20G  9.3G  9.4G  50% /
    tmpfs                              3.0G  8.0K  3.0G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs                              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs                              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /run/shm
    /dev/sda2                          976M  198M  712M  22% /boot
    /dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
    /dev/loop2                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
    /dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
    /dev/loop3                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19032
    /dev/loop4                          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
    /dev/loop5                          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
    tmpfs                              595M     0  595M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Why are there three folders using 3Gb each and how can I get rid of them? I am running one single service on this machine so I doubt it is needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is using 3G. These are tmpfs. They are not stored on disk, only in RAM. And they only use any relevant amount of RAM, if there are actually files in there (which is not the case on your system).